# ZeroMQ request and multiple async replies to this request

Tags: asynchronous, design-patterns, zeromq

I have something like remote machine that performs heavy computations and a client machine that sends tasks to it. Output results are very big from megabytes to gigabytes and come in chunks during long time period. So it looks like this:
client sends task and then needs to receive this chunks since they are already useful (one request - multiple responses). How to realize this pattern in ZeroMQ.

Comment: Have you read [the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all)? I recommend it if you're going to be creating a messaging implementation on top of ZMQ yourself.  But, the short short short answer is to use something like `DEALER` <-> `ROUTER` since the communication is bidirectional and not strictly send/receive/send/receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I read the problem above definition wrong, but as it stands, it seems to me that the main concern is achieving a **way to accomodate a message flow between a pair of hosts** ( not a Broker fan-out to 1+ Workers using classical `DEALER/ROUTER` Scaleable Formal Communication Pattern ),
**where

the key concern** is, how to handle
a **client-machine** ( sending one big-computing-task-request and "waits" for a flow of partial results )
to an **HPC-machine** ( receiving a TaskJOB, processing it and delivering a flow of non-synchronised, unconstrained in time and size messages back to the client-machine ).

For such a 1:1 case, with 1-Job:many-partialJobResponses, the setup may benefit from a joint messaging and signalling infrastructure with several actual sockets under hood, as sketched below:

### Signalling:

```
clientPUSH   |-> hpcPULL    // new TaskJOB|-> |
clientPULL <-|   hpcPUSH    //              <-|ACK_BEGIN
clientPULL <-|   hpcPUSH    //              <-|KEEPALIVE_WATCHDOG + PROGRESS_%
clientPULL <-|   hpcPUSH    //              <-|KEEPALIVE_WATCHDOG + PROGRESS_%
...                         //                |...
clientPULL <-|   hpcPUSH    //              <-|KEEPALIVE_WATCHDOG + PROGRESS_%
clientPULL <-|   hpcPUSH    //              <-|KEEPALIVE_WATCHDOG + PROGRESS_%
clientPULL <-|   hpcPUSH    //              <-|ACK_FINISH         + LAST_PAYLOAD#
clientPUSH   |-> hpcPULL    // new TaskJOB|-> |
clientPULL <-|   hpcPUSH    //              <-|ACK_BEGIN
...                         //                |...
clientPULL <-|   hpcPUSH    //              <-|ACK_FINISH         + LAST_PAYLOAD#
```

### Messaging:

```
clientRECV <-|   hpcXMIT    //              <-|FRACTION_OF_A_FAT_RESULT_PAYLOAD#i
clientACK    |-> hpcACK     // #i POSACK'd|-> |
clientRECV <-|   hpcXMIT    //              <-|FRACTION_OF_A_FAT_RESULT_PAYLOAD#j
clientRECV <-|   hpcXMIT    //              <-|FRACTION_OF_A_FAT_RESULT_PAYLOAD#k
clientACK    |-> hpcACK     // #k POSACK'd|-> |
clientACK    |-> hpcACK     // #j   NACK'd|-> |
clientRECV <-|   hpcXMIT    //              <-|FRACTION_OF_A_FAT_RESULT_PAYLOAD#j
clientACK    |-> hpcACK     // #j POSACK'd|-> |
clientACK    |-> hpcACK     // #u   NACK'd|-> |               // after ACK_FINISH
clientACK    |-> hpcACK     // #v   NACK'd|-> |               // after ACK_FINISH
clientACK    |-> hpcACK     // #w   NACK'd|-> |               // after ACK_FINISH
clientACK    |-> hpcACK     // #x   NACK'd|-> |               // after ACK_FINISH
clientRECV <-|   hpcXMIT    //              <-|FRACTION_OF_A_FAT_RESULT_PAYLOAD#x
clientACK    |-> hpcACK     // #x POSACK'd|-> |
clientRECV <-|   hpcXMIT    //              <-|FRACTION_OF_A_FAT_RESULT_PAYLOAD#u
clientACK    |-> hpcACK     // #u POSACK'd|-> |
...                         //                | ...      
clientRECV <-|   hpcXMIT    //              <-|FRACTION_OF_A_FAT_RESULT_PAYLOAD#w
clientACK    |-> hpcACK     // #w POSACK'd|-> |
```

again, using a pair of `PUSH/PULL` sockets for (internally)-state-less messaging automata, but allowing one to create one's own, higher level Finite-State-Automata, for self-healing messaging flow, handling the **`FAT_RESULT`** controlled fragmentation into easier to swallow payloads ( remember one of the ZeroMQ maxims, to use rather a Zero-Guarrantee than to build an un-scaleable mastodont ( which the evolutionary nature of the wild ecosystem will kill anyways ) and also providing some level of reactive re-transmits on demand.

Some even smarter multi-agent setups are not far from gotten sketched to increase the processing throughput ( a  **`FAT_RESULT`** DataFlow **Curator agent**, separate from the **`HPC_MAIN`**, unloading the HPC platform's resources for immediate start of next **`TaskJOB`**, etc )

Comment: Yes you see the problem clearly. But why not to use signaling (push/pull) to send the actual data along with keep alive messages in between?

Comment: Glad it helps. The reason why ( for the proposed separation of messaging from signalling ) is based on the previous experience with separation of responsibilities and scaling in near-real-time distributed architectures.

Comment: @user3666197I have a feeling that you're a pro in distributed system architectures. Can you give me some explanation (like for newbie) how exactly this separation helps when I want to scale the system (a the moment it is not the case but still). Another question what if I know that the system architecture will not change can I use this simplified (push/pull) approach or I still have some benefit from using two connections. If yes please explain it a bit even if it is obvious for you.

Comment: Hope it would not sound too academic, but separation of responsibilities addresses a need to have a clean and robust boundary, which object and whose methods handle the internal state of some Finite-State-Automaton ( sometimes you need to prove a non-blocking behaviour, for which the FSA-s are great tool for ). Once you change your mind into such way of thinking, you can also better hard-code the separate sections in non-OO environments, where more rudimentary language constructs are being used ( for the sake of squeezing the latency and code-footprint, for (near)RT systems ).Separation helps.

Comment: @user3666197Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use async pattern (DEALER-ROUTER).

Look at this topic [The Asynchronous Client/Server Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-Asynchronous-Client-Server-Pattern)

And at the example in [Java](http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:asyncsrv) or [C#](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cs:asyncsrv)

But keep in mind that ROUTER socket can drop your messages if its [HWM](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#High-Water-Marks) is reached.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this